# D3 get particular elements value of json example

Tags: mysql, d3.js

I have a json example like this:

```
[
 {"emp_name":"ABC","works_on":"wheels","time_from":"2012-03-27 10:00:00","time_to":"2012-03-27 12:00:00"},
 {"emp_name":"xyz","works_on":"seat","time_from":"2012-03-27 14:00:00","time_to":"2012-03-27 17:00:00"},
 {"emp_name":"ABC","works_on":"painting","time_from":"2012-03-28 10:00:00","time_to":"2012-03-28 12:00:00"},
 {"emp_name":"xyz","works_on":"tube","time_from":"2012-03-28 14:00:00","time_to":"2012-03-28 17:00:00"},
 {"emp_name":"pqr","works_on":"engine","time_from":"2012-03-29 10:00:00","time_to":"2012-03-29 12:00:00"},
 {"emp_name":"ABC","works_on":"wiper","time_from":"2012-03-29 14:00:00","time_to":"2012-03-29 17:00:00"},
 {"emp_name":"mno","works_on":"air_cooler","time_from":"2012-03-30 10:00:00","time_to":"2012-03-30 12:00:00"},
 {"emp_name":"ABC","works_on":"wheels","time_from":"2012-03-30 14:00:00","time_to":"2012-03-30 17:00:00"},
]
```

I don't know if there is a way to count total working hours for each employer.

Comment: SO is not for writing everything. Give us an existing project in jsfiddle or so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly you want to count total work times for each  `emp_name`.

Just need to use this code:

```
var data = [
        { "emp_name": "ABC", "works_on": "wheels", "time_from": "2012-03-27 10:00:00", "time_to": "2012-03-27 12:00:00" },
        { "emp_name": "xyz", "works_on": "seat", "time_from": "2012-03-27 14:00:00", "time_to": "2012-03-27 17:00:00" },
        { "emp_name": "ABC", "works_on": "painting", "time_from": "2012-03-28 10:00:00", "time_to": "2012-03-28 12:00:00" },
        { "emp_name": "xyz", "works_on": "tube", "time_from": "2012-03-28 14:00:00", "time_to": "2012-03-28 17:00:00" },
        { "emp_name": "pqr", "works_on": "engine", "time_from": "2012-03-29 10:00:00", "time_to": "2012-03-29 12:00:00" },
        { "emp_name": "ABC", "works_on": "wiper", "time_from": "2012-03-29 14:00:00", "time_to": "2012-03-29 17:00:00" },
        { "emp_name": "mno", "works_on": "air_cooler", "time_from": "2012-03-30 10:00:00", "time_to": "2012-03-30 12:00:00" },
        { "emp_name": "ABC", "works_on": "wheels", "time_from": "2012-03-30 14:00:00", "time_to": "2012-03-30 17:00:00" }
    ];
```

This function `d3.nest().key(function (d) { return d.emp_name })` will group your data by `emp_name`.

```
    var nest = d3.nest().key(function (d) { return d.emp_name })
        .rollup(function(v) {
            return d3.sum(v, function (d) {
                //Convert time to standard format
                var sTimeTo = d.time_to;
                var splitedTimeTo = sTimeTo.split(" ");
                splitedTimeTo = splitedTimeTo[0] + "T" + splitedTimeTo[1];

                var sTimeFrom = d.time_from;
                var splitedTimeFrom = sTimeFrom.split(" ");
                splitedTimeFrom = splitedTimeFrom[0] + "T" + splitedTimeFrom[1];
               //cal difference between time_to and tim_from 
                var timeTo = Date.parse(splitedTimeTo);
                var timeFrom = Date.parse(splitedTimeFrom);
                var deltaTime = timeTo - timeFrom;
                //convert date from milli s to an hour
                deltaTime = Math.ceil(deltaTime / (1000 * 3600));
                console.log(deltaTime);

                return deltaTime;
            });
        })
        .entries(data);

    console.log(JSON.stringify(nest));
```

Complete jsfiddel [here](http://jsfiddle.net/zzjebraeil/ghgqhxf2/1/).

Comment: Instead of giving data manually , is it possible to load external json data file (data.json) which contain above data and use d3.nest...????

Comment: Yes you can load data from json file. Check [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/zKNTjw1Kl2R35JGTWJQM) sample. I changed your question to valid json and count again. This sample could help you to realize the `d3.json()` function, [here](http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/8329447).

Comment: Seriously hats off, Thank you very much .

Comment: One Last thing , i just want to bring in "works_on" field also . For example : "ABC" works on "wheels" , "painting","wiper" . so how long "ABC" working in each field...??? "ABC"'s total working hour we got it , his individual time that he spends on each depatment...??

Comment: Please give me your json example and what you want, then I'll answer it. it's complicated now

Comment: Thank you for your reply. What i want is , i want to plot a pie chart of total working hour of each employee ( ex : if you consider above example , ABC's total working hour is 10 , xyz's 6 etc.. ) and when you click particular employees name on the pie chart , it has to plot a bar chart showing , on which department each employee is spending how much time ( for ex : ABC is working on wheels , painting and wiper , what i want is a bar chart showing  each employee showing how much is working in each department )  can you please help me

Comment: As you mention I change my answer and hope help you. [This](http://plnkr.co/edit/cR21AOi6x5WizYgztVWI?p=preview) is total work for each department for each employer.

Comment: Thank you very much. Its working . But i am very much confused with presenting it. Like i want two pie chart , one showing the total working hour of each employee and other showing working hour in a particular department. I have created a drop down list also,which shows the list of employee . Either you select name from list or from the pie chart (which shows the total working hour of each employee)  it has to plot one more pie/bar chart showing each department details and working hour of that particular employee. I am very much confused , please please help me in visualization part also.

Comment: Till now i have done [This](http://plnkr.co/edit/s75M6XsZuGsH5Z7jv5wV?p=preview) much work. please correct it.

Comment: I am not understanding how to collect values from d3.nest() function.

Comment: How ever you have told , i have done like that only , but reading values from data file ...???

Comment: Are you looking for example like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/zzjebraeil/g07qc516/), I create a pieChart for total work hours for each employer.

Comment: Thank you for the code. Yes i was looking something like this thank you. But i want one more bar chart to be added , if you click particular employee on the present pie chart ( which shows the total working hour of each employee ) it should plot one more bar chart which shows the details of that employee (like how long that employee was working on each department) like x-axis date & time , y-axis hours and on the bar department name. can you please help me. I will also try . if i got something i will post it. but please help me. Thank you , thank you very much for your replies.

Comment: And one more thing , can you please give me an idea . Like how to read data file from server and plot it on browser ( For ex : Some machine is there that will generate data file or log file once in a day and it will get stored in server machine , by accessing that data file i want to plot using D3.js on browser ) is it possible ...?? because i am new to this programming field and if yes please give any good tutorials.

Comment: Do you ever work with `XML` document or looking for create json with database model or JavaScript serialization ? for first step serialize your data from database to json with every programming language you work and then visualize it with d3.

Comment: But before that can you help me with this : - "i want one more bar chart to be added , if you click particular employee on the present pie chart ( which shows the total working hour of each employee ) it should plot one more bar chart which shows the details of that employee (like how long that employee was working on each department) like x-axis date & time , y-axis hours and on the bar department name. can you please help me. I will also try . if i got something i will post it. but please help me. Thank you , thank you very much for your replies"

Comment: I'm working on it and will let you know when it's complete.

Comment: Thank you very much. I think its something like [This](http://bl.ocks.org/diethardsteiner/3287802#index.html)

Comment: Is it possible to use "AngularJS" from reading data from server and plot that data using D3 library...????

Comment: Yes, AngularJS is one of the most powerful Library that I know, [This](http://jsbin.com/zinu/1/edit?html,css,js,output) is an example could help you to use D3 and Angularjs.

Comment: Hello.... Which is the best option for crating  a **"Data visualization Dashboard" **, is it **D3js** or **google chart** .....???? Like for my requirement , have to read data from server (either it can be json,csv,xml or text) and have to plot it on browser... can you please help me in choosing the best library.... What could be the role of **Angulajs** in this....???? Is it helpful.

Comment: Google chart is a strong chart visualization and good to fast create chart but it's not flexible, you can test your project with Google Chart, but I prefer to work with d3js both of them is compatible with Angularjs. I prefer d3js because i could create my chart step by step and change it easily.